# Flash AS3 stage.colorCorrectionSupport always resolves to unsupported - what happened to stage.colorCorrection?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, colors

Two and a half years ago Adobe announced that FlashPlayer 10 would support color correction. Admittedly the implementation was really basic because it would always assume all content to be sRGB encoded and would convert that content to the current display profile in use on the system. [This was the introduction blog post by John Nack.](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2008/10/get_better_color_online_through_flash_play.html)

All AS3 needed to activate this feature is:

```
stage.colorCorrection = ColorCorrection.ON;
```

...and yes you do need stage access for this to work and no that is not the problem.

So back when it was new I wrote a little wrapper to display images in Internet Explorer and Chrome so that they would render correctly for folks with extended gamut displays and also used this in a flash based video player with the same purpose.
Revisiting either today I find that what I know to have worked no longer does. What changed in the meantime is FlashPlayer's version and most likely the browser versions, too. I tried OS X, Win 7, Win XP, icc v2 and icc v4 display profiles on all of these, different browser versions, flash player versions to no avail.
You'll say that I must have done something wrong but the  [example page Adobe published a while later](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/color_correction_as3.html) and which I lknow to have worked for sure also fails nowadays. If you look at the Flash applet you'll find it saying:

```
stage.colorCorrectionSupport: unsupported
```

If it sais supported for your system please comment the OS, browser and version and FlashPlayer version. Otherwise I'm looking for any clues to what happened to this feature.

[At least the Adobe staff participating on their boards seems to be clueless.](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5284066) Quote: *Because this feature seems to be disabled by default in most major browsers, I'm thinking that it was an experimental web standard proposal that died or something.  We're not doing a whole lot here, it's mostly dependent on the browsers passing us the right data and doing the right color conversion math.  We're pretty far down the chain of events.*

I know for a fact that this worked at some point of FlashPlayer's evolution. So the following might help in solving what's going on:

- does the Adobe example still work for anyone caring to look?
- if this were about a deprecated browser feature why doesn't it work on old browsers anymore?
- did it stop working on any particular FlashPlayer? (I tried several but could no longer make it work)

Notes:

- color correction did not work with wmode transparent for some reason (but opaque was fine)
- color correction originally also sometimes failed when using alpha bleding transitions

**UPDATE:** The feature still seems to work when wmode is set to "window". Of course that is very limiting. If you have a lightbox etc. on a page the Flash content will always stay on top of it etc. - so that's bad.
With wmode="window" the example also worked for me on OSX 10.6 (only version I tested thus far) and Win XP 32 bit. It still failed with all win 64 bit versions I tried but those systems have multiple screens so maybe I'll have to retry with a single screen since the first comment below suggests it worked on Win 7 64. 
On the systems this worked I tried Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer and Chrome. All worked the same except that when using Chrome the built-in Flash player always gives `stage.colorCorrectionSupport: unsupported` while disabeling the built-in FP and using the system's Flash player works as in the other browsers.

So the questions above can be narrowed to why does this no longer work for any other wmode especially "opaque" - which did work before and which is what Adobe uses in their on-line version of the sample file...

**UPDATE 2:** Flash Player's newer wmodes "gpu" and "direct" make the feature fail on the systems / browsers named above where wmode "window" worked out.

**UPDATE 3:** After finding the wmode = "window" angle I decided to post a follow-up on the Adobe forum I quoted from initially. That lead to this whole issue being acknowledged as a bug in Flash player at: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3596843 So I guess there won't be an answer to the question of what happened to stage.colorCorrection but hopefully it will sort itself out.

**UPDATE 4:** O.k. here is the mandatory bit of stupidity... When I said that I remembered wmode "opaque" to have worked before I errored. Upon reviewing this further I found that a long time ago I had put `wmode="normal"` in one of my JS files and since `normal` does not exist older versions of Flash Player used the standard wmode `window` so that was why it worked back then. More modern Flash Players have other defaults e.g. `direct` where color management fails and so it failed for me. So I think this never worked with any wmode other than "window" but I'm curious what the future might bring for this...

Comment: I tried the example swf [provided](http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flash/quickstart/color_correction_as3/_jcr_content/articlePrerequistes/multiplefiles/node_1279269672685/file.res/color_correction_flash_player.zip).
It seem to work when i directly opened the (local) swf in FireFox -> stage.colorCorrectionSupport: defaultOff. I can see some realy small changes when i click 'toggle'.
Firefox is 22.0, OS is Win7(64), flash is 11.7.700.224

Comment: @djib thanks for the hint, what you found is that the feature still seems to work with wmode "window" see update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(yeah this is an old question, but I was product manager for Flash Player 10, so I thought I'd answer)

It works with window mode because Flash Player gets the rectangle in the browser and gets pretty much full control of the rendering stack and doesn't have to deal with compositing with items it doesn't know the color status of.

When you switch to something like wmode transparent, you go into a pretty crazy back and forth process compositing with the rendered elements above and below it.  When you go into wmode GPU, the rendering stack is largely handed over to the GPU (not surprisingly).  In both cases, Flash Player loses some control of the rendering stack and at that point things like color correction aren't possible.

The primary reason for this feature in Flash Player 10 was to enable interactive e-publishing in Flash Player (like inDesign SWF export) as well as support for applications that could help in a print-oriented tool chain.